# Call Oracle stored procedure from linked server with refcursor output

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, linked-server

I need to Call a Oracle Stored Procedure from a linked Server in SqlServer.THe oracle Stored Procedure has a refcursor output.

I am using the following code to call the procedure from SqlServer

```
exec
(
'
variable customerdetails refcursor
begin
exec PROC_GETCUSTOMERDETAILS(:customerdetails)
end
print customerdetails
'
) at (Linkedservername)
```

When i use the inner query directly in oracle it returns me output.But when i use it in a linked server it is returning me 0 Rows.

Comment: "But when i use it in a linked server it is returning me 0 Rows" - likely to be permissions

Comment: Do you know any particular permission that i need to set??